# typescript styled component extend not working when I fixed props no spreading

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, extends

typescript styled component extend not working when I fixed eslint props-no-spreading

I don't understand why this doesn't apply.

If I use the props, it will be applied.

but, If I fix jsx-props-no-spreading eslint, it won't be applied.
Please help me.

1. It's working

```js
const Button = (props: buttonType): JSX.Element => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
  return <ButtonBlock {...props} />;
};
```

2. It's not working

```js
const Button = ({
  children,
  red = false,
  fullwidth = false,
  disabled = false,
  onClick,
}: buttonType): JSX.Element => (
  <ButtonBlock
    fullwidth={fullwidth}
    onClick={onClick}
    disabled={disabled}
    red={red}
  >
    {children}
  </ButtonBlock>
);
```

3. It's also not working

```js
export const TestButton3 = (props: buttonType): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <ButtonBlock fullwidth={props.fullwidth} red={props.red}>
      {props.children}
    </ButtonBlock>
  );
};
```

button type and ButtonBlockcomponent

```js
type buttonType = {
    children?: any;
    to?: string | undefined;
    red?: boolean | undefined;
    fullwidth?: boolean | undefined;
    disabled?: boolean | undefined;
    onClick?: (() => void) | undefined;
}


const ButtonBlock = styled.button<buttonType>`
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: gray;
  ${(props) =>
    props.red &&
    css`
      background: red;
    `}
  ${(props) =>
    props.fullwidth &&
    css`
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      line-height: 2rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5rem;
    `}
`;
```

using component code

```js
import Button from '../../components/common/Button';


const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  color: red;
`;

render(
  <StyledButton fullwidth onClick={onClick}>
      My Button
  </StyledButton>
)
```

Let me know why this is happening

Comment: What do you mean : it does not work? Do you have eslint error?